# Relationship between 3 Models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a relation between 3 Models in Laravel 5.6

Here are my tables

**departments**

- id
- name

**subjects**

- id
- name

**teachers**

- id
- name

**teach**

- id_teacher
- id_department
- id_subject

The relationship between all tables is many to many.

- Teacher can teach many subjects in many department
- department belongs to many subject
- subject belongs to many department

How to make these relationships inside the Teacher, Department and Subject Models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Department extends Model
{
    /**
     * The teachs that belong to the department.
     */
    public function teachs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teach', 'teach_department', 'department_id', 'teach_id');
    }
}

class Subject extends Model
{
    /**
     * The teachs that belong to the subject.
     */
    public function teachs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teach', 'teach_subject', 'subject_id', 'teach_id');
    }
}

class Teacher extends Model
{
    /**
     * The teachs that belong to the teacher.
     */
    public function teachs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teach', 'teach_teacher', 'teacher_id', 'teach_id');
    }
}

class Teach extends Model
{
    /**
     * The departments that belong to the teach.
     */
    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Department', 'teach_department', 'teach_id', 'department_id');
    }

    /**
     * The subjects that belong to the teach.
     */
    public function subjects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subject', 'teach_subject', 'teach_id', 'subject_id');
    }

    /**
     * The teachers that belong to the teach.
     */
    public function teachers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Teacher', 'teach_teacher', 'teach_id', 'teacher_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. how can I sync all those models?
I tried this.

$teacher = new Teacher();
$teacher->name = $request->name;
$teacher->save();

$teach = new Teach();

$teach->teacher_id = $teacher->id;
$teach->departments->sync($request->departments, false);
$teach->subjects->sync($request->subjects, false);